# How to take each string (hostname) from an output?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am trying to write a script using bash that performing show command and takes each hostname (string) from the show output and perform action (show command) on it.

For example:

```
root@Router2:~$ show routers

Hostname1

Hostname2

Hostname3
```

And i want to take each hostname (hostname 1, hostname 2 and hostname3) and perform action on each one of them.

Here is what i manage to do:

```
figlet Status code
u=$(tput smul)
b=$(tput bold)
n=$(tput sgr0)

echo "${b}${u}Enter server's name${n}"
read -e server
echo ""
Routershow$=(show routers)
```

After that, i want to take each string (hostname) from the $Routershow output. How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, not clear, could you please elaborate your question more here. If needed add sample(s) of Input and output too in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `while read x` command where "x" is a variable name:

```
show routers | while read routerName
do
    echo $routerName
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [loop](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/) over all items (hostnames) that result from your command (show routers). For example:

```
for hostname in $(show routers)
do
  # access each hostname here. e.g.
  echo $hostname
done
```

or as extension to your script:

```
...
Routershow=$(show routers)
for hostname in $(echo $Routershow)
do
  # access each hostname here. e.g.
  echo $hostname
done
```